# Getting front() Of Empty vector Yields Unexpected Behavior

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have a vector, which contains a class object. 
I declared like this

```
vector<Aircraft> queue;
```

I erase the first element in the vector. But it seems like the first element still in the vector. I did this.

```
queue.erase(queue->begin());
cout<<queue.size(); //printed 0 
Aircraft temp = queue.front();
cout<<temp.id; //expected a segfault error
```

The size of the vector is 0 after I erased the first element (there was only one element).
I was expecting a seg fault error when I tried to see the id of temp (Aircraft) since I erased the first element from the vector and the size is zero after that.
I even cleared the vector but *'queue.front*' still returns the object and *cout* statement still prints the id of the object.

Comment: [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) is undefined -- anything can happen.

Comment: If you want to do that, perhaps you should use a different container.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's *undefined behavior* to access the `front()` of a `vector` that is empty so you must not do it and you can't infer anything from the apparent behavior of your program if you do do it.

The fact that `queue.size()` is one less than before the `.erase` call should tell you that `erase` has worked.

Answer (score 0):

Likely, you are heading off into undefined behavior. The vector doesn't have to zero out the memory.

Answer (score 0):

The typical vector implementation usually has a stack buffer of say 16 elements. Grow the vector up to that size and no mem allocation happens. So even after deleting the element the memory is still there (like a cache, but ready to be used) and unless Aircraft cleans itself on destructor you're going to see the same values.

Do this experiment: poison the id (to say -1234) in Aircraft destructor and re-run your code. Keep it just as a learning experiment since it's bad practice to rely on such things as poison values.

Also add another item to the vector and then print the front again. You'll get the new item.

Also try running your code compiled in debug mode and you'll get an assert when calling front() where you'd expect a crash. Always run new code in debug mode, that's what it's there for.